How to create this table without words going out of the box?
I used the following code:
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\textbf{Prototype} & \textbf{Dataset} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Comparison}} \\ \cline{3-5} 
 &  & \textbf{State of Art Work} & \textbf{Evaluation Metric} & \textbf{Results} \\ \hline
Prototype 1, Prototype 2 \& Prototype 3 & MNIST & PyVertical & Accuracy & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Prototype 1 achieves \\ higher accuracy by 0.44\% \\ Prototype 2 achieves \\ higher accuracy by 3.41\% \\ - Prototype 3 achieves \\ higher accuracy by 3.32\%\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Prototype 1, Prototype 2 \& Prototype 3 & Fashion MNIST & - & - & - \\ \hline
1 & Titanic & Flower & Accuracy & Higher VFL Accuracy Plot over Rounds \\ \hline
1 & Adult & Wei et. al. [15] & AUC curve & Better AUC curve \\ \hline
1 & Bank Marketing & Split NN Max Pooling [16] & Accuracy, F1 Score & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Higher F1 score by 23\% \\ But lower accuracy\end{tabular} \\ \hline
1 & Give Me Some Credit & Split NN Max Pooling [16] & Accuracy, F1 Score & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Higher Accuracy by 6\% \\ Higher F1 Score by 1\%\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comparison of State of Art Work, Evaluation Metric, and Results for Different Prototypes and Datasets}
\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}

I am trying to get the table like shown in MS Word

Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question to include a compilable document that people can play with. For example, the C and Y column types aren't part of standard LaTeX, so how are they defined? You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the {} icon in the editor.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You haven't provided a definition of the Y column type, so I'll assume it's something like \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}, where \RaggedRight is a macro provided by the ragged2e package.
Your use of single-column tabular environments, with c as the column type, in column 5 defeats the purpose of the Y column type.  The fix? Just get rid of the tabular wrappers.
I'd also get rid of all vertical lines -- trust me, they won't be missed -- in order to give the table a more inviting and open look.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx}   % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % ?
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYYYY @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Prototype} & \textbf{Dataset} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Comparison}} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){3-5} 
 & & \textbf{State of Art Work} & \textbf{Evaluation Metric} & \textbf{Results} \\ 
\midrule
Prototype 1, Prototype 2, Prototype 3 & MNIST & PyVertical & Accuracy & 
Prototype~1 achieves higher accuracy by 0.44\%; \newline 
Prototype~2 achieves higher accuracy by 3.41\%; \newline 
Prototype~3 achieves higher accuracy by 3.32\%. \\ 
\midrule
Prototype 1, Prototype 2, Prototype 3 & Fashion MNIST & -- & -- & -- \\ 
\midrule
1 & Titanic & Flower & Accuracy & Higher VFL Accuracy Plot over Rounds \\ 
\midrule
1 & Adult & Wei et al.\ [15] & AUC curve & Better AUC curve \\ 
\midrule
1 & Bank Marketing & Split NN Max Pooling [16] & Accuracy, F1~Score & 
Higher F1 score by 23\%, but lower accuracy \\ 
\midrule
1 & Give Me Some Credit & Split NN Max Pooling [16] & Accuracy, F1~Score & 
Higher Accuracy by 6\%; \newline 
Higher F1 Score by 1\%.  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comparison of State of Art Work, Evaluation Metric, and 
         Results, for different prototypes and datasets}
\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Addendum: While the above table satisfies the requirement that none of the cell contents protrude into the margins, there's a lot of wasted space because the columns have equal widths. It would be better if the column 5 could be made (a lot!) wider than columns 1 thru 4. This can be fixed by employing a variable-width variant of the Y column type.

Column 5 is now (at least) twice as wide as any of the first 4 columns. And, I've streamlined the table's look some more, by (a) getting rid of bold-facing the header rows and (b) replacing the interior \midrule directives with \addlinespace instructions.
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx}   % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for '\RaggedRight' macro
%% create a variable-width version of 'Y' column type:
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt

% Note: 0.9+0.65+0.8+0.85+1.8 = 5.0 = # of Y-type columns
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Y{0.9}Y{0.65}Y{0.8}Y{0.85}Y{1.8} @{}}
\toprule
Prototype & Dataset & 
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Comparison} \\ 
\cmidrule{3-5} 
 & & State of Art Work & Evaluation Metric & Results \\ 
\midrule
Prototype 1, Prototype 2, Prototype 3 & MNIST & PyVertical & Accuracy & 
Prototype~1 achieves higher accuracy by 0.44\%; \newline 
Prototype~2 achieves higher accuracy by 3.41\%; \newline 
Prototype~3 achieves higher accuracy by 3.32\%. \\ 
\addlinespace
Prototype 1, Prototype 2, Prototype 3 & Fashion MNIST & -- & -- & -- \\ 
\addlinespace
1 & Titanic & Flower & Accuracy & 
Higher VFL accuracy plot over rounds \\ 
\addlinespace
1 & Adult & Wei et~al.\ [15] & AUC curve & Better AUC curve \\ 
\addlinespace
1 & Bank Marketing & Split NN Max Pooling [16] & Accuracy, F1~Score & 
Higher F1 score by 23\%, but lower accuracy \\ 
\addlinespace
1 & Give Me Some Credit & Split NN Max Pooling [16] & Accuracy, F1~Score & 
Higher accuracy by 6\%; higher F1 Score by 1\%.  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comparison of State of Art Work, Evaluation Metric, and Results, for different prototypes and datasets}
\label{tab:comparison}
\end{table}

\end{document}

